# using & with array returned unexpected result

Tags: c

I have been learning C and came across the following code. I know what it does but I don't know why it does that.

```
char str[5] = "hele";
printf("string is %s: \n", &str[1]);

output:
ele
```

Why does &str[1] output ele? From what I have read so far, & returns the address hence shouldn't &str[1] returns the address of "e". Since the output is 'ele', I know this is not the case but I can't figure out why.All help appreciated.

Comment: &str[1] does return the address. The %s in the printf function uses it as the start of the string and will continue until it encounters a null terminator. Thus ele.

Comment: this `&str[1]` is the address of the second element in the string array, arrays index starts from 0, so the first element is `&str[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the prototype of `printf`:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

and it goes with conversion specifiers like %d, %a, %s, %c...

if `%s` is used, the `const char *` argument is expected to be a pointer to an array of character type (pointer to a string).

**Back to your case:**

`&str[1]` does point to `'e'` and it is a *pointer to string* so the argument of `printf` has obviously correct type.

And what `printf` does next, see the good quality comment of Cobster

> The %s in the printf function uses it as the start of the string and
>   will continue until it encounters a null terminator

Answer (score 0):

It's because a C string is just a number of characters in memory followed by a null character. `str` has some address in memory, and `&str[1]` is equivalent to `str + 1` (the array gets turned into a pointer in that expression). What you get is a pointer to the middle of the original string, which will be also be a valid string, just missing the start.

What it looks like in memory is like this:

```
[h ] [e ] [l ] [e ] [\0]
 ^ str points here
```

When `printf` prints the string, it takes in a pointer to the first character just like most functions that deal with strings and prints characters until it hits the terminating null (`\0`). If you instead pass in `str + 1`, it'll happily print the part of the string starting from index 1.

Comment: No a C string is **not** a pointer. Quoting the C standard: "A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character." ... "A *pointer to a string* is a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character."

Comment: @KeithThompson: *Sigh*... better?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Why would you sigh about that? The distinction between a pointer and the thing it points to is not trivial; Keith is not merely being pedantic.

Comment: @immibis Well, he *is* being pedantic, but the computer will be even more pedantic, so he's right to do so. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a string in c is basically an array of characters. So your string actually contains

```
h (position 0) e (position 1) l (position 2) e (position 3) \0 (position 4)
```

Everything in brackets is just for explanation.

The `&` operator returns the address of a variable, or the address of an element of an array.

So when you do

```
printf("string is %s: \n", &str[1]);
```

`&str[1]` return the address of `str [1]`. If you would put `%c` in printf, the value of element of `str [1]`, which is `e`, would get printed. But when you put `%s`, `printf` takes it as the start of the string from where it has to be printed, and thus prints the string till it encounters the null terminator (`\0`).

For better explanation:

> There is a string, which has the contents `hele`. `h` is the 0th element, `e` is the 1st element, `l` is the 2nd element, `e` is the 3rd element, and `\0` as the fourth element. The string is basically a char array, in which each element is a `char`. Each of them have an address. So doing `&str [1]` returns the address of the 1st element of the `char array`. Then, `%s` takes that as the start of the string to be printed, and prints the string till it encounters the null-terminator (`\0`). Thus, it takes the start of the string as 1st `e`, or the 1st element. Then prints `l` and `e`, after which it encounters the null-terminator, where it stops.